# S3 to Google Storage using transfer service

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

In AWS I have folder format like `eg : Bucketname/Data/files/abc_01-02-2022.csv`
In a increment order I have files for each dates for all the months in year.

In Google Cloud Storage I am trying to create folder structure like `eg:Bucketname/data/202202/files/abc_01-02-2022.csv` for whole year

So, I am trying to use storage transfer service which will take dynamically or from object itself and create a folder structure automatically by getting trigger automatically 2nd of the month.

Can we achieve this by using transfer service.
what is the best way to achieve this I am trying to make it simple as possible

Answer (score 1):

Storage Transfer Service does not support destination object prefixes, the reason behind it is, Storage Transfer Service [doesn’t support remapping](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-console#select), that is, you cannot copy the path `Bucketname/Data/files/` to `Bucketname/data/202202/files`

My recommendation would be to first use the Storage Transfer Service to copy everything from one bucket to another and later use any of the available [methods to rename the object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/copying-renaming-moving-objects#rename) in the new bucket to `Bucketname/data/202202/files`.

Also the Cloud Storage Objects are flat namespaces, that is, Cloud Storage does not have folders and sub folders. There are a few documents that you can refer to for more information on this [Object name considerations](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-objects#object-considerations) and [Folders](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible via using [STS API](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/TransferSpec#gcsdata). You can specify "path" at the destination bucket.